# Need to understand the GROUP BY in this query

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1064

> We define an employee's total earnings to be their *monthly salary × months worked*, and the *maximum total earnings* to be the maximum total earnings for any employee in the **Employee** table.
> Write a query to find the maximum total earnings for all employees as well as the total number of employees who have maximum total earnings.
> Then print these values as two space-separated integers.
> ([Top Earners at hackerrank.com](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/earnings-of-employees/problem))

I am a beginner in SQL and couldn't understand the solution which was given

```
/*1.*/ SELECT (months*salary) as earnings,
/*2.*/   COUNT(*) FROM Employee
/*3.*/   GROUP BY earnings
/*4.*/   ORDER BY earnings DESC
/*5.*/   LIMIT 1;
```

I understood the first step where we are giving months*salary an alias which is `earnings`.
In the 2nd step we are counting the no. of employees from the `Employee` table.
I didn't understand why we are using `GROUP BY` here,
4th and 5th step are also clear, we use the `ORDER BY` clause in order to rank earnings from highest to lowest, and `LIMIT 1` will fetch me the highest value.

But why `GROUP BY`?

(Ignore 1,2,3,4,5: These are just numbers I used for better clarity.)

Comment: To anyone feeling inclined to answer this question: they ask for an explanation here, *not an alternative*.

Answer (score 4):

You have splitted the query errorneously.

Must be:

```
SELECT (months*salary) as earnings, -- 2 and 4
       COUNT(*)                     -- 4
FROM Employee                       -- 1
GROUP BY earnings                   -- 3
ORDER BY earnings DESC              -- 5
LIMIT 1;                            -- 6
```

Step 1 - table `Employee` is used as data source

Step 2 - the value of the expression `(months*salary)` for each record in the table is calculated

Step 3 - the records which have the same value of the expression from (2) are treated as a group

Step 4 - for each group the value of the expression from (2) is put into output buffer,  and the amount of records in a group is calculated and added to output buffer

Step 5 - the rows in output buffer are sorted by the expression from (2) in descending order

Step 6 - the first row from the buffer (i.e. which have greatest value of the expression from (2)) is returned.

Comment: @HarshitaSingh Step 4 is a step when output values are calculated. What is unclear precisely?

Comment: suppose my earnings are 1,1,2,3,4,5
So count(*) will count the number of earnings of employees, which is six
and group by clause will group similar earnings together?

Comment: @HarshitaSingh your earnings will be divided to 5 groups with separate values 1,2,3,4,5. For each group the amount of records in a group will be calculated giving 2,1,1,1,1 respectively (two rows with earning=1, one row with earning=2, ...).

Comment: I am confused what count function is doing here. Everything is so messed up

Answer (score 2):

**Step 3:** `GROUP BY earnings` was used to GROUP TOGETHER same value earnings. If you have, for example, earnings of $3,000, and there were 3 of them, they will be grouped together. `GROUP BY` is also required in combination with the aggregate function `COUNT(*)`. Otherwise, `COUNT(*)` will not work and return an error.

**Step 4:** `ORDER BY earnings DESC` was used to order the GROUPED EARNINGS in DESCENDING order. Meaning, from HIGHEST EARNINGS down to the LOWEST EARNINGS.

**Step 5:** `LIMIT 1` limits the returned row count to only 1.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Okay, so you mean we always use group by whenever we use count function?

Comment: Yes! More generic answer would be, you use GROUP BY when you use AGGREGATE FUNCTIONS.

Answer (score 1):

GROUP BY aggregate your Results. When there are multiple numbers of "earnings" with a same value is just a single one in your table.

Comment: But it wasn't giving multiple earnings with same value, there was actually no need of it. What is your take on that?

Comment: Yes, in this example is no need for that. But SQL queries should always be open for all possibilitys of data. If in this example an employee get a salary increase an have now the same earning like a other you could use the same query with better performance as without GROUP BY. And because you return only the first line of results, you can see (because COUNT(*)) How many employees get this earning.

Comment: But when I did not use group BY clause, I didn't get my answer

Comment: thats because you use Count(*)

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT TOP 1 (months * salary), COUNT( * ) 
  FROM Employee GROUP BY (months * salary) 
  ORDER BY (months * salary) DESC;
```

---

use above one for MS SQL server.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please, when answering a question with code, don't post just the code. Add an answer alongside it, explaining what your code does and why it solves the question. Thanks.

Comment: Doesn't answer the question. They're looking for an explanation, not an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Use MySQL

```
select (months * salary) as earnings, -- select employee's total earnings to be their monthly  worked
count(*) -- select all data
from Employee 
group by earnings -- group by earnings to find the count of the number of employees who have earned max 
order by earnings desc -- order by descending to get the height earning to lowest earning 
limit 1; -- get the heighest earning and total number of employees who have maximum total earnings
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this query:

```
SELECT months*salary,COUNT(*) FROM Employee GROUP BY months*salary having count(*) = 7 ORDER BY months*salary DESC;
```

Comment: Doesn't answer the question. They're looking for an explanation, not an alternative.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT
    MAX(salary * months), COUNT(*)
FROM
    Employee
GROUP BY
    (salary * months)
ORDER BY
    (salary* months) desc limit 1;
```

Comment: Hi, and thanks for the answer. I believe it would greatly help everyone if you could explain why and how this answer solves the OP's problem!

Comment: Doesn't answer the question. They're looking for an explanation, not an alternative.

Answer (score -1):

```
select (salary * months) as max_earning -- for selecting max_earning
,count(*)                       -- for counting total employees with max_earning
from employee                   --table from which data is fetched
Group by (salary * months) desc --grouping the max_earning in desc order
limit 1;                        -- selecting the 1 record with max_earnings.
```

This code is for MYSQL

Comment: What does this add to the information given in the question? How does it answer *But why GROUP `BY`?*

Answer (score -1):

```sql
select max(salary*months), count(*)
  from employee
 where (salary*months) in (
    select max(salary*months) from employee
   )
```

this is implemented in MySQL

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Doesn't answer the question. They're looking for an explanation, not an alternative.